# NodeJS web service generates some strange request urls

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I'm running a web service that has been developing in NodeJS and ExpressJS, on the EC2 instance running CentOS in the free tier of Amazon Web Service for a few days ago. Recently, I noticed that the web service has received some strange request urls from log file:

```
GET http://www.baidu.com/?rands=18054347 200 16ms - 170b
GET http://118.123.4.111:800/proxyheader.php?rands=84016821 200 14ms - 1.29kb
GET http://www.soso.com/?rands=84016821 200 15ms - 170b
GET http://116.255.157.223:800/proxyheader.php?rands=27086218 200 21ms - 1.29kb
GET http://reg.renren.com/?rands=51868686 200 14ms - 170b
GET http://reg.163.com/?rands=83858874 200 15ms - 170b
GET http://mail.126.com/?rands=83858874 200 21ms - 170b
GET http://www.so.com/?rands=35720251 200 12ms - 170b
GET http://udb.yy.com/register.do?rands=35720251 200 12ms - 1.29kb
GET http://azenv.net/ 200 9ms - 170b
```

The normal request (from my client) should be logged:

```
GET /free-gifts/load-list?username=tientest 200 3ms - 149b
POST /promotes 200 128ms - 43b
```

I don't know where these requests come from, because my web service is still in the development mode and my client application hasn't published yet.

Thank you for reading my question!